# Binding Jquery events in backbone

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js

I have a jquery datepicker component which im trying to listen to using backbone. The jquery documentation mentions the onSelect event, so i tryed doing the following:

```
events: {'onSelect #date-picker': 'dateSelected'},

dateSelected: function(){
   console.log('date selected');
}
```

but the dateSelected function does not get called. A standard javascript event like click gets called. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Try with `select` instead of `onSelect`:

```
events: {'select #date-picker': 'dateSelected'},

dateSelected: function(){
   console.log('date selected');
}
```

Comment: That didnt help unfortunatly.

Comment: There are multiple possible explanations for your problem. More diagnostic would require the DOM and complete view code. (For example, calling $().html multiple times will kill the event handlers)